# Is following inequality true?

Tags: inequality

I would appreciate if someone could help me with this problem.

Assume $a$, $b$ and $c$ are real positive values where $a^2 +  b^2 +c^2 =1$.

Is it possible to prove that  $ab+ac+bc\leq 1$?

obviously special cases e.g. $a=b=c=1/3$ hole for the case of equality but I am interested in a general solution.

Comment: That is just an instance of the rearrangement inequality.

Comment: Hint: prove that $ab+bc+ca \le a^2+b^2+c^2$ for $\forall a,b,c \ge 0\,$.

Comment: Further hint: $$0\leq (a-b)^2+(a-c)^2+(b-c)^2=\ldots$$

Comment: many thanks for the hints!

Answer (score 0):

$$1-ab-ac-bc=a^2+b^2+c^2-ab-ac-bc=\sum_{cyc}(a^2-ab)=$$
$$=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{cyc}(2a^2-2ab)=\frac{1}{2}(a^2+b^2-2ab)=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{cyc}(a-b)^2\geq0$$